# Increment value when the field is the same

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

First, I'm sorry for the ambiguous title. 
Here's my problem :
I'm using Access and I have this table :

```
+--------+-----------+
| PARENT | CHILD     |
+--------+-----------+
| JOHN   | TANIA     |
| JOHN   | ROBERT    |
| JOHN   | APRIL     |
| HELEN  | TOM       |
| HELEN  | GABRIELLE |
+--------+-----------+
```

And I would like to add a column like this with queries or VBA code :

```
+--------+-----------+---------+
| PARENT | CHILD     | LIST    |
+--------+-----------+---------+
| JOHN   | TANIA     | CHILD 1 |
| JOHN   | ROBERT    | CHILD 2 |
| JOHN   | APRIL     | CHILD 3 |
| HELEN  | TOM       | CHILD 1 |
| HELEN  | GABRIELLE | CHILD 2 |
+--------+-----------+---------+
```

I want to do this because at the end, I want to run a cross tab query. I'm only missing that last column to create that query.

1. I tried to do it in a recordset, but my database starts bloating after a couple of rst.Update (I have 700k+ rows)
2. I created a temporary table and used UPDATE queries but it just takes too much time.

I think there might be a SQL code that would do what I need, but I just can't figure it out. I hope you could help me, thanks :)

Comment: I cant' edit right now (looks like someone else is editing at the time), but It would be nice to format that table properly. It took me a while to figure out what were you talking about :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still trying to figure out how to format it :p I tried to add an image to be clearer but it doesn't work ^^'

Comment: Is the data in an excel file or are you trying to pull the data into Excel from SQL?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it in my message, I'm going to edit it. The tables are in Access. Eventually, I will export it in .csv format.

Comment: if you want to u can import the data to mssql and try to use "row_number" to add the list number. then export it again to access

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I'd like to compute everything on Access. I'm using Fionnuala's method right now.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the below, but it would be much better with some sort of IDs:

```
SELECT Parent.PARENT, 
     Parent.CHILD, 
    (SELECT Count(*) 
     FROM Parent p 
     WHERE p.Parent=Parent.Parent 
     AND p.Child<=Parent.Child) AS ChildNo
FROM Parent
ORDER BY Parent.PARENT, Parent.CHILD;
```

Parent is the name of the table.

[image: query result]

Comment: Thank you Fionnuala. It does exactly what I want. It runs faster than my own codes, and I think it can be even faster with some indexes :)

Comment: Hi Fionnuala, I would like to use the result of your query as an input for a cross query. Unfortunately, the query doesn't work (it says something like "Access doesn't recognize [Parent].Parent as a field name"). I think I should apply parameters into your query for the WHERE clause but I'm not sure what to put as a parameter. Do you have any ideas ? :p